# Magento Connect Authorisation credentials

Tags: magento2, vagrant

I am currently in the process of setting up a VM (using Vagrant) with Magento 2, however a step of the process requires me to generate a public and private key for Magento. I am trying to follow the instructions as provided by Magento themselves [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html), however I am stuck at the step "4. At the top of the page, click Connect", since there is no "Connect" link/button. I'm unable to find anywhere else in my account where I can generate these keys and am unable to contact Magento Support since I am only using Community edition for now. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Once you log in, go to this [link](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/extension/extension/list/) then you can see as mentioned in the image. there you have option called security keys where you can see.

Hope this helps ...:)

Comment: Thanks - slightly misleading instructions on the Magento docs, since it leads you to the Marketplace :)